# how to fix bootstrap responsive mobile menu open delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

At the first time the bootstrap responsive mobile menu open has a stuck in the middle of the page for a while then dropping down. And also rest of the time has a delay when menu dropping down, at the same time menu close works well without any delay.

I have tried with

```
.collapsing{
  height: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

but still open take delay when compare with closing

**DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwMvmv**

---

### Question update

In the normal stage menu element seems like this

```
<div id="toggle-menu" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

It toggle class `collapse` to `collapsing` and also calculate menu height  add that height in to inline css `style="height:250px;"`

```
<div id="toggle-menu" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse collapsing" style="height:250px;">
```

after collapse completed inline css backed and class switch to `collapse in"`

```
 <div id="toggle-menu" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" style="">
```

Actually I just need to bypass the `collapsing` and inline css of menu `height`

I need to bypass the `.collapsing` class injection 
[image]

Comment: the issue is here `.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 240px;
}` the height: 240px

Comment: Dirty fix is set  `height: 100%` and add `padding-top: 80px;` to `.navbar-default .navbar-nav` selector

Comment: @Shehary As where I understand the issue is in the jQuery. jQuery run inline css as menu height then our css runs

Comment: If I remove your custom CSS, i don't see any problem with the drop-down without CSS http://jsfiddle.net/b9cmg3u3/1/ and if CSS added then this http://jsfiddle.net/b9cmg3u3/2/ and if ` height: 100%` and  `padding-top: 80px;` then this http://jsfiddle.net/b9cmg3u3/2/ (it's a dirty fix so i see the problem still exist) but i don't see any reason the issue is in the jQuery because even if i remove the height the issue still exist, so i replace the padding with margin here http://jsfiddle.net/b9cmg3u3/3/ and it seems working properly, no height define

Comment: @Shehary still the issue occur. navmenu closing speed and opening speed are not the same. I will update my question with more explanation

Comment: I noticed first time the menu opens fast and onwards open and close slow, so you want it to keep opening fast or you want it to open slow even first time?

Comment: you also forget to mention that menu behaving differently in different browsers, in chrome its acting weird like open n try to collapse and then open first time but in firefox it just open fast firsttime and onwards speed slow

Comment: @Shehary I have just updated with question. Hope you clould understand what I am looking and also appreciated for your efforts so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87571/discussion-between-muhammed-athimannil-and-shehary).