# How do I fix open and close delay for mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a navigation menu. I'm using Bootstrap 5, but I modified the default menu snippets a little bit. The problem is when I open and close the mobile menu, there is a slight delay.

Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/dtommy79/pen/xxXYQdr

I tried to disable elements one by one to see if any of those causes the issue, but didn't.

I also tried to remove the transition from the `.navbar-elements` class, but it isn't causing the problem.

I also tried some of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124537/how-to-fix-bootstrap-responsive-mobile-menu-open-delay), but it didn't solve the issue for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the padding on line 277 to a different element from the one you're showing/hiding, like a menu container inside `.navbar-elements`.